# LINQ 3 times nested foreach and get value from middle loop

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

In my application I have the row id and I need to retrieve the field id that owns that row.

In foreach I would write it like this:

```
Field ownerField;

foreach (Sparter sparter in account.GetSparters())
{
    foreach (Field field in sparter.GetFields())
    {
        foreach (Row row in field.GetRows())
        {
            if (row.Id == rowId)
            {
                ownerField = field;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I write this in LINQ? I thought it should be something like this, but this is not correct:

```
Field field = account.GetSparters()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetFields()
    .Find(f => f.GetRows()
    .Where(r => r.Id.Equals(rowId))));
```

Comment: Is there only one record with that id?

Comment: @GiladGreen yes, the id of that row is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that:

```
Field field = account.GetSparters()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetFields())
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetRows()
                      .Any(r => r.Id == id)
     );
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I notice now that I was placing the ')' wrong